# Wordpress Media Count and Next Page Navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

Users are allowed to upload and access media files from front end. I am using following code which retrieve media files and show on user front end. I have 40 media files in my wordpress uploads but I want to show e.g. 20 media files at single page and I wonder if someone can help to write previous & next page navigation code for media files. e.g Page 1 2 3 ... 10

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
/* 'posts_per_page' => '2', */
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => null,
'author' => $current_user->ID,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
);
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo '<tr><td><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID).'" rel="shadowbox" title="'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'">';
echo ($attachment->_wp_attached_file);
echo '</a>      
</td>
</tr>'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I wrote my solution

```
<?php 

$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$args = array(                                                          
    'post_type'     => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page'=> '10',
    'paged'     => $page,
    'numberposts'=> -1,
    'post_status'   => 'any',
    'author'        => $current_user->ID,
    'post_parent'   => $post->ID,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
    'number'        =>  $display_count,


);

// Custom query, display posts by args defined users
$file_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$attachments = get_posts( $args );

if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    echo '<tr><td><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID).'" rel="shadowbox" title="'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'">';
    echo ($attachment->_wp_attached_file);
    echo '</a>      
    </td>

    </tr>'; 
    }    
}

?>
```

Call query funtion in in your code

```
<?php previous_posts_link( '<< Previous Page', $file_query->max_num_pages ); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php next_posts_link( 'Next Page >>', $file_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the standard wordpress navigation.

Try to change your $args like this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
  'paged' => $paged
);
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'posts_per_page' => 20,
'paged' => $paged,
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => null,
'author' => $current_user->ID,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
);
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo '<tr><td><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID).'" rel="shadowbox" title="'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'">';
echo ($attachment->_wp_attached_file);
echo '</a>      
</td>
</tr>'; 
}
?>
```

UPDATE 2

Also you need to use this function

Post it somewhere below your posts

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$navArgs = array(
    'base'         => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format'       => '?page=%#%',
    'total'        => 1,
    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'show_all'     => False,
    'end_size'     => 1,
    'mid_size'     => 2,
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
    'type'         => 'plain',
    'add_args'     => False,
    'add_fragment' => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number' => ''
); 

echo paginate_links( $navArgs );
```

As you can see you can set navArgs the way you like.

You need to get a total count of your posts and set the 'total' parameter.

Comment: Thanks, above code limit the media/posts 20 per page but numbers of next pages are not appearing on the page?

Comment: Try to set 5 posts per page and see if the numbers will appear. Also delete numberposts parameter.

Comment: I made that change and that doesn't seem to help, I removed numberposts parameter and set 5 posts per page. I think it gonna work if we add "previous" and "next" pages numbers and links after the loop. If I correct can you please help me how?

Comment: Describe the current effect after you have made the changes. What does it show. What do you see in the navigation?

Comment: I made change and that doesn't seems to help, nothing change but I see last 5 media/posts. Result doesn't show me the page numbers and I can't see my files which I upload earlier.

Comment: approach looks right to me but my div tag comes empty where I paste your second update, No page numbers and I can't see my previous media files as well

Comment: You need to get a total count of your posts and set the 'total' parameter. See the decription of this function in the wordpress manual https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links - fallow it carefully.

Comment: I also tried http://adambalee.com/how-to-add-pagination-to-your-wordpress-blog-without-a-plugin/ but I don't know why pagination in my theme is not working

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website where you try this? Can you post the whole code (not just a part)? Don't just say that it doesn't work. try to describe reactions and responses that you get after you have made changes.

Comment: I am working on my localhost. I update my solution. Thanks @user1551066